# Fast STL way to find input that produces maximum output of function? (contiguous integer inputs)

Tags: c++, stl

To improve the readability, I'm trying to get out of the habit of reinventing the wheel.

### Problem:

Consider a black-box function, `Foo`, which has an integer as input and output. We want to find the input that maximises the output. Consider that all the possible inputs belong to a single, contiguous range of integers; and that the range is small enough that we can try each one.

Speed is important, so we don't use containers. ***Even if the user has already created a container for all the possible inputs***, it's still about 100x faster to calculate the next input (`++input`) than to get it from memory (cache misses).

### Example:

Range: **[5, 8)**

```
Foo(5); // 19
Foo(6); // 72
Foo(7); // 31
```

We want to make a function that should return `6`:

```
InputOfMaxOutputOnRange(5, 8, Foo); // 6
```

### Custom solution:

```
template <typename T, typename Func>
T InputOfMaxOutputOnRange (T begin_range, T end_range, Func && Scorer)
{    
    // initialise:
    auto max_o = Scorer(begin_range);
    T i_of_max_o = begin_range;

    // now consider the rest of the range:
    ++begin_range;

    for (T i = begin_range; i < end_range; ++i)
    {
        auto output = Scorer(i);

        if (max_o < output)
        {
            max_o = output;
            i_of_max_o = i;
        }
    }
    
    return i_of_max_o;  
}
```

### Question:

I use functions like this so often that I think there should be an STL way to do it. Is there?

Comment: DO you have both both vectors with you? Or rather do you have the associated output vector? If not, do you have the function? Either way, unless you have the vector, we cannot be able to tell how to get `6` as an answer

Comment: @Onyambu, there is no vector. that's the point. This is a range.

Comment: So you do not have the Associated output before hand? Do you then have the function? How did you get `19,72,31`?

Comment: @Onyambu, that's right. There's a function being called. My example code has it as `LhsMoreThanRhs`. You get the output from calling the function.

Comment: if you have a function that should be optimized (in your case-maximized) then you should consider using the NLOPT package or even use the `brent` method in boost library to be able to solve this

Comment: @Onyambu, Thanks, it's true that I'm wanting to optimise this function, but all I need is literally the function I've written above. I'm not sure that it would help readability to use a third-party library just for a 5-line function. Libraries like `NLOPT` are more useful when you can't exhaustively look at the entire search space, or if there's some pattern to take advantage of to disregard some of the search space.

Comment: How's the assosiation stored?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, nothing here is being stored. There's no containers at all.

Comment: What you have is already enough. So I only suggested in case there is an issue. To me the you provided is succinct enough

Comment: Ok, how do you assosiate 5 with 19 and 6 with 72 etc?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, the function calculates it.

Comment: Ok, so something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/EevYGM) would be an option?

Comment: @TedLyngmo It seems there is an underlying function within the Comparator, that does the handywork and so as to the code OP provided here, nothing much can be done

Comment: @Onyambu Except perhaps the part about not reinventing the wheel. I'm not sure what OP thinks about adding a small custom iterator to use with `max_element`.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a wrapper around whatever type you'd like to use in a range iterator. Perhaps the C++20 ranges library has this built in - I haven't read up on that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I'm stupid. I didn't see that you wrote `rit`. it's clever, but swaps one customisation for another. I'd happily upvote it as in interesting answer.

Comment: @Onyambu No, you don't need a container. Check my example.

Comment: @Elliott I hope there's something in the C++20 standard that can provide the same as the `rit` I made - I was looking at `ranges` but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: @TedLyngmo huh. I see. Sorry, i completely missed that.

Comment: @Elliott Apparently, there's a boost version of `rit` (as answered by Marshall Clow) so I'd go with that version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++20 ranges can do this:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename F>
T argmax_iota(T begin, T end, F &&score) { // can't really think of a good name for this; maybe it doesn't even deserve its own function
    return std::ranges::max(std::views::iota(begin, end), std::less{}, std::ref(score));
    // over the values in the range [begin, end) produced by counting (iota)...
    // find the one that produces the greatest value (max)...
    // when passed to the projection function score...
    // with those values under the ordering induced by std::less
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cranges%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T,+typename+F%3E%0AT+argmax_on(T+begin,+T+end,+F+%26%26score)+%7B%0A++++return+std::ranges::max(std::views::iota(begin,+end),+std::less%7B%7D,+std::ref(score))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::vector+v%7B100,+100,+100,+100,+100,+19,+72,+31%7D%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+argmax_on(5,+8,+%5B%26%5D(auto+i)+%7B+return+v%5Bi%5D%3B+%7D)+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:67.0721666936558,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:32.927833306344205,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g102,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-O3%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+Executor+(Editor+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:32.927833306344205,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

`iota` does not store the whole range anywhere. Iterators into the range hold a single `T` value that is incremented when the iterator is incremented.

Comment: This is what I was looking for when making my own counting iterator.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the algorithms in the STL work on sequences of values, that are traversed by iterators. They tend to return iterators as well. That's the pattern that it uses.

If you're doing a lot of things like this, where your input "sequence" is a sequential list of numbers, then you're going to want an iterator that "iterates" over a sequence (w/o any storage behind it).

A little bit of searching turned up [Boost.CountingIterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html), which looks like it could do what you want. I'm confident that there are others like this as well.

Warning - completely untested code

```
    auto iter = std::max_element(boost::counting_iterator<int>(5),
                                 boost::counting_iterator<int>(8),
          // a comparator that compares two elements
                                );
    return *iter; // should be '6'
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have observed, `std::max_element` is defined to get the largest element in a a range.

In your case, the "iterator" is an integer, and the result of dereferencing that iterator is...some result that isn't related to the input in an obvious (but apparently you have some way to getting it efficiently nonetheless).

This being the case, I'd probably define a specialized iterator class, and then use it with `std::max_element`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

// your association function goes here. I've just done something
// where the relationship from input to output isn't necessarily
// immediately obvious
int association_function(int input) {
    int a = input * 65537 + 17;
    int b = a * a * a;
    return b % 127;
}

class yourIterator {
    int value;
public:
    // create an iterator from an int value
    explicit yourIterator(int value) : value(value) {}

    // "Deference" the iterator (get the associated value)
    int operator*() const { return association_function(value);  }

    // advance to the next value:
    yourIterator operator++(int) {
        yourIterator temp(value);
        ++value;
        return temp;
     }

     yourIterator &operator++() {
        ++value;
        return *this;
    }

    // compare to another iterator
    bool operator==(yourIterator const& other) const { return value == other.value; }
    bool operator!=(yourIterator const& other) const { return value != other.value; }

    // get the index of the current iterator:
    explicit operator int() const { return value; }
};

int main() {
    // For demo, print out all the values in a particular range:
    std::cout << "values in range: ";
    std::copy(yourIterator(5), yourIterator(10), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"));

    // Find the iterator that gives the largest value:
    yourIterator max = std::max_element(yourIterator(5), yourIterator(10));

    // print out the value and the index that gave it:
    std::cout << "\nLargest element: " << *max << "\n";
    std::cout << "index of largest element: " << static_cast<int>(max);
}
```

When I run this, I get output like this:

```
values in range: 64     90      105     60      33
Largest element: 105
index of largest element: 7
```

So, it seems to work correctly.

If you need to use this with a variety of different association functions, you'd probably want to pass that as a template parameter, to keep the iteration part decoupled from the association function.

```cpp
// pass association as a template parameter
template <class Map>
class mappingIterator {
    int value;
    // create an instance of that type:
    Map map;
public:
    // use the instance to map from iterator to value:
    int operator*() const { return map(value);  }
```

Then you'd have to re-cast your association function into a form suitable for use as a template parameter, such as:

```cpp
struct association_function {
    int operator()(int input) const {
        int a = input * 65537 + 17;
        int b = a * a * a;
        return b % 127;
    }
};
```

Then in `main` you'd probably want to define a type for the iterator combined with an association function:

```cpp
    using It = mappingIterator<association_function>;
    It max = std::max_element(It(5), It(10));
```

Comment: Nice! I'd only change b from int to long since "a * a * a" may result in overflow.

Comment: @RonaldSouza: that function is just a placeholder, so its working well isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::max_element` defined in `<algorithm>`.

This will return the iterator to the maximum element in a specified range. You can get the index using `std::distance`.

Example copied from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

```
 std::vector<int> v{ 3, 1, -14, 1, 5, 9 }; 
 std::vector<int>::iterator result;
 
 result = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
 std::cout << "max element at: " << std::distance(v.begin(), result) << '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, however this isn't the same thing. It's far too inefficient.

Comment: @Elliott: Not sure how it's inefficient; it lacks the keyed operation you requested, so it's not a complete answer, but it's perfectly efficient.

Comment: @Elliott Could you elaborate more? Your code snippet essentially does the linear scanning of elements in range which is what max_element does too

Comment: @Elliott needs the overload of `max_element` that takes a comparator, and pass his `LhsMoreThanRhs` there.

Comment: @Eugene, for large ranges, say 0 to 40,000, this would be about 100x slower. So it's simply not a worthwhile option, even if it makes my code more readable.